Splitting lemma for Non-abelian groups (semi-direct product)
I was reading the wikipedia page to learn about how the splitting lemma partially holds for non-abelian groups. Splitting lemma partially true
$$ 0\to A \to B \to C \to 0 $$
If a short exact sequence is right-split, then $B$ is a semi-direct product. But which semi-direct product? $A\rtimes C$? or $C \rtimes A $?
A short explanation of why that holds would also be immensely helpful.
Thanks!

$C$ is the group acting on $A$; I forget which direction that is in terms of the symbol you're using.
You can tell because $A$ is the one that's normal in $B$. So $B$ naturally acts on $A$ by conjugation, and a right splitting $s : C \to B$ allows us to restrict this to an action of $C$ on $A$.

My dumb mnemonic is: $A$ is the normal subgroup [of the semidirect product], so $A \triangleleft$, so $A \rtimes C$. This mnemonic is, unfortunately, not supported by latex: $A \triangleleft$ versus $A \rtimes C$
